# Highchart heatmap grouped category plugin styling issues

Tags: highcharts

[image]

Could someone please help me with following styling issues?

1. Why are the categories not having line segmentation like shown in the column chart on plugin website? See the red marked area
2. I would like to have minorGridlines property from HighChart to clearly de-markate the categories. In the example i have 2 sub categories for each category. How can i add minorgridlines at 2 category interval from highchart? Something like green lines in the picture is what i would like in the graph.

Here is my fiddle for the same https://jsfiddle.net/k16sdhrz/

```
 chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
},

yAxis: {
    categories: [{
            name: 'Cat 1',
            categories: ['Item 1_1', 'Item 1_2']
        },
        {
            name: 'Cat 2',
            categories: ['Item 2_1', 'item 2_2']
        }
    ]
},
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Increase `tickWidth` property (0 - by default)
2. Use `plotLines` option:

---

```
yAxis: {
    tickWidth: 1,
    labels: {
        x: -5
    },
    plotLines: [{
        value: -0.5,
        color: 'green',
        width: 5,
        zIndex: 10
    }, ...]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ekcq2td8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickWidth