# Grouped categories heatmap

Tags: r, dplyr, r-highcharter

I am trying to create heatmap with grouped categories in X axis. Code works partially but it returns the labels of x axis in wrong position. For example : Egypt 1952 should have 1418 but the code posted here returns 2444 which is a value of Bulgaria.

**Source of code :** [Grouped categories for a highcharter heatmap in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780609/grouped-categories-for-a-highcharter-heatmap-in-r)

```
library(gapminder)
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(100)
x_country = sample(gapminder$country,20)

dat<- select(gapminder, continent, country, year, gdpPercap) %>%
  filter(country %in% x_country)
dat=droplevels(dat)

categories_grouped <- dat %>%
  distinct(continent,country) %>% 
  rename( name =continent) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  do(categories = .$country) %>% 
  list_parse()

highchart() %>%
  hc_yAxis(categories = dat$year) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = categories_grouped) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = dat,type = 'heatmap',hcaes(x=country,y=factor(year),value=gdpPercap)) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(minColor = "#FFFFFF", maxColor = "#434348")
```

Comment: I got different labels on the x-axis using your code: https://imgur.com/a/aLgTAvF. It looks like you're calling the x-axis labels from the list `categories_grouped` and the y-axis from `dat`.

Comment: which version you are using? In the latest version you need to call dependency of grouped category

Comment: I'm using highcharter 0.8.2.

Comment: You need to add hc_dependency() function